# Why code for capturing video is not working in one plus?

Tags: java, android

I used video capturing code using built-in camera in an application, but it reporting issues some of android phones like OnePlus phones. in other phones it works perfectly, can anyone help me to solve this issue, i tried many times but it didn't work, I'm sharing my code below..

Acutually it is shows only in device like one plus, I try to use built-in cam for to recording video, in my project, After we click button for to record video, it will redirected to the built-in cam in the device, in other devices it's working perfectly. but in one plus version11 , after we click the button for to record video it will not redirected to built-in cam, it is just stuck with the same page.. this is the issue

private void captureVideo() {

```
Intent VideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
if (VideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    VideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
    VideoIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
    VideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 3);
    VideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_FINISH_ON_COMPLETION,true);

    startActivityForResult(VideoIntent, VIDEO_REQUEST);

}
```

}

Comment: what are the issues ? do you have some logs to share ?

Comment: We definitely need more information. Everything else is as much a guess as if you'd ask "my car doesn't work, why?". One _assumption_ on your problem: did you check for the specific Android variant that's delivered with those phones? Some vendors alter the permissions or funcitonality to some degree, e.g. it seems access to app statistics is allowed in vanilla Android but not in the Samsung variants. The same could be happening in your case.

Comment: @a_local_nobody      Acutually it is shows only in device like one plus, I try to use built in cam for to recording video, in my project, After we click button for to record video, it will redirected to the built-in cam in the device, in other devices it's working perfectly. but in one plus version11 , after we click the button for to record video it will not redirected to built-in cam, it is just stuck with the same page.. this is the issue.